# setup of mandrill on local development (localhost)

Tags: php, symfony, mailchimp, mandrill

How can I setup Mandrill account to getting work on local develoment like localhost, so I can send email from localhost and get some related statistics. 
I can send emails from Production server successfully but not from localhost.

Issues:

1. Currently I am getting "Unsigned" error in Json reponse from Mandrill on local dev when I send mails from local.
2. Getting blank array [] while searching search-time-series.json

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you use a Mandrill development key?

Comment: You do this in local dev just like you'd do it anywhere else. You should post your code so we can see what might be going wrong.

Comment: It should work just fine with the same configuration as your server. Check that the following properties are setup correctly: **host**, **port**, **protocol**,**username**, **password**.
If it does not work still, please post the code and the errors which you are getting.